# Capturar exceptions no spring

Tags: web-service, spring

Pessoal estou usando Spring e queria saber como posso retornar os erros (exception) da @Repository e/ou @Service para o meu webservice?

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
[ Webservice ] ------ [ @service/@Transactional ] ------- [ @Repository ]
```

Quando lançar alguma exception no meu DAO qual a  forma elegante de tratar e retornar para o meu webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Depende do webservice, caso seja SOAP você vai gerar um FAULT como resposta... Em geral isso já é mapeado automático quando você gera os stubs... Caso esteja utilizando http puro, rest, basta retorna um status condizente com o erro. Por exemplo: 500 para dizer que aconteceu um erro inesperado, 400 para indicar parâmetros ruins...